Error injecting: MainAnnotationProcessorMojo ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors
I have a java application which I have upgraded from java8 to java11 with maven 3.3.9. I have a plugin:
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1->5.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>process</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.15.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>

When I run integration tests, I receive the following error:
[INFO] --- maven-processor-plugin:5.1:process (process) @ MyModule ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.MainAnnotationProcessorMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting: private org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionRangeResolver.logger
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionRangeResolver
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.VersionRangeResolver
    for parameter 2 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.DependencyCollector
    for parameter 5 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  while locating org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.MainAnnotationProcessorMojo
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger field org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionRangeResolver.logger to org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.slf4j.Slf4jLoggerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanPropertyField.set(BeanPropertyField.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders.firstOf(BeanProviders.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders$7.get(BeanProviders.java:160)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders.firstOf(BeanProviders.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders$7.get(BeanProviders.java:160)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(PlexusRequirements.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

2) Error injecting: private org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.logger
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.VersionResolver
    for parameter 2 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.ArtifactResolver
    for parameter 2 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  while locating org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.MainAnnotationProcessorMojo
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger field org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.logger to org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.slf4j.Slf4jLoggerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanPropertyField.set(BeanPropertyField.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders.firstOf(BeanProviders.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders$7.get(BeanProviders.java:160)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders.firstOf(BeanProviders.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders$7.get(BeanProviders.java:160)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(PlexusRequirements.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

3) Error injecting: private org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.logger ...    
4) Error injecting: private org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger ...

